# Editing Bootstrap Classes Using SASS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to edit the Bootstrap jumbotron to display a background image. I'm using SASS to do this. This is what I currently have in my scss file:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables";

$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #0074a9,
    "danger": #f1f124
);

@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

.jumbotron{
    @extend .jumbotron
    background-image: url("../assets/banner.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: center;
}
```

I think I messed up the imports somewhere, but I'm not sure where. Thanks!

Edit:
File tree:

```
Site
-assets
----banner.png
-bootstrap
---(bootstrap js and css files)
-scss
---custom.scss
---custom.css
---custom.css.map
-index.html
-styles.css
-style.css.map
```

fyi: custom.css and styles.css is identical

[This](https://pastebin.com/xdk4dRi0) is the css file that is linked in the html.

Comment: I'm guessing your error is on the `.jumbotron`? You're extending it with itself, which doesn't make sense. This is CSS it compiles to, so the Bootstrap version will be defined before — you can safely override properties in `.jumbotron`. Basically, remove `@extend .jumbotron` (syntactically, you were also missing a `;` at the end by the way).

Comment: That didn't work either though. I tried adding ; and removing the extend.

Comment: I believe Bootstrap works a bit differently and has a pretty clear boilerplate to import your own stuff. Could you provide us with the compilation error?

Comment: There's no compilation error, it just doesn't display the background image like it's supposed to.

Comment: Let's say your file is in a `/main/styles/` folder: is your image in a `main/assets/` folder? Trying to see if this issue is just URL-related (you can check in the DevTools network tab if the image has loaded).

Comment: Everything there is either JSON, CSS, or SCSS, no PNG. Is my path incorrect? I clicked onto the debugger tab and found out that the folder containing the image is not listed, what could've caused this?

Comment: Without seeing your whole setup, it's tough to debug. Do you have an assets pipeline that processes your images?

Comment: I'm still a beginner with SASS and web development so I have no idea what that means. I did everything in the most basic way possible, just downloaded an image, put it in a folder and linked the image in the SASS file.

Comment: No worries, sorry if I confused you. Could you provide a file tree to see where all your files are located? As well as your compiled CSS, if possible.

Comment: I edited both of them into the original post.

Comment: Looks like your style.css file is at the root of the site. `../` looks into the parent folder, so your banner URL is saying "look up a folder" (so the parent folder of `Site`) "then look into the `assets` folder for `banner.png`), i.e.: `SiteParent/assets/banner.png`. To fix this, remove a dot: `url("./assets/banner.png");` and your CSS should look into `Site/assets/banner.png`. The error you are apparently making is looking for the file relative to your pre-compiled file, not your final file.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot that. Now it works, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure thing! Sometimes your nose is just too close to your code to notice things like that, and you need a fresh pair of eyes to help. :)